# How to programmatically launch console/terminal and change its current directory to a certain path?

Tags: parameters, console

How to programmatically launch console/terminal and change its current directory to a certain path?

Language: C++/Qt, but I'm sure here the language doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems that support the C library `system()` call, you could just directly launch a command shell. What command depends on OS:

- For Windows, you want something like:

  ```
  cmd /k cd \my\directory
  ```

  (escape backslashes as necessary)
- For Unix variants, it could be an X11 terminal program with options to specify command to run:

  ```
  xterm -e 'cd /tmp/ && bash'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "cd" command (in the console) to change the directory. I believe that should work on most platforms.